# Depend on both input arg and derived collection in re-frame

Tags: clojurescript, re-frame

Just started using re-frame and encountered following difficulty. I have a component ([Form-2](https://github.com/Day8/re-frame/wiki/Creating-Reagent-Components#form-2--a-function-returning-a-function)) which takes one arg, creates `reaction` based on it, and returns renderer like this

```
(defn some-list [some]
  (let [bars (rf/subscribe [:bars (:id @some)])]
    (fn [some]
      [:ul
       (for [[id b] bars]
         [:li (:name b)])])))
```

Later i call it with

```
(defn some-dashboard [some]
  [:div.some-dashboard
   [some-list some]])
```

`some` is reaction. Here when i call `some-list` with `[]` it binds to initial `some` thus `bars` always have same `(:id @some)` in subscription and get the same value from subscription.

Could you please tell me how to fix it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found answer on clojure slack community.

It turned out to be a dynamic subscription https://github.com/Day8/re-frame/pull/108. PR is coming.

Workaround is:

- put the data in  @some into app-db  ....
- so it can be accessed in the handler itself

Code

```
(defn some-list []
  (let [bars (rf/subscribe [:bars])]
    (fn []
      [:ul
       (for [[id b] @bars]    ;;   <---------- remember the @
         [:li (:name b)])])))

(register-sub 
   :bars
   (fn [db _] 
     (let   [some   (reaction (get @db :some)]  
        (reaction  (get-in @db [:bar @some] ))))
;; we should NOT be using the name "some" ... I'm only doing it so it relates back to your question
```

That's how dynamic subscriptions will solve this problem (taken from [here](https://clojars.org/re-frame/versions/0.5.0-SNAPSHOT)). Original example found [here](https://github.com/Day8/re-frame/commit/018ecca0e0c813e7c0ffe00ee5689d81bd27d6f1).

```
(defn some-list [some]
  (let [some-id (reaction (:id some))
        bars (rf/subscribe [:bars] [some-id])]
    (fn [some]
      [:ul
       (for [[id b] @bars]
         [:li (:name b)])])))
```

And that's how subscriber looks (it's quite identical to code from commit message above):

```
(rf/register-sub
  :bars
  (fn [db _ [some-id]]
    (reaction (get-bars @db some-id))))
```

Note for myself: don't forget to remove generated js files when moving to next re-frame version.